# create R data frame script from CSV or clipboard

Tags: r

Is there any online tool that allows for converting a table to an R script that creates a data frame script.

I would like to paste 5 rows of `cars` df and get this:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    speed = c(4,  4, 7,  7,  8),
    dist  = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 16)
  )
```

I want an equivalent of CSV to SQL insert. Here is example https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm
which generates this code:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   speed INTEGER  
  ,dist  INTEGER 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (4,10);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (7,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (7,22);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (8,16);
INSERT INTO mytable(speed,dist) VALUES (9,10);
```

Please note that I do not want to read data from CSV directly. I just want to create a data frame script. for reprex purpose.

Comment: dput(DF) will convert data frame DF to R code that you can include in a script.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it trims data. It recreates only 6 rows.

Comment: The df in your question has 5 rows and dput(df) will produce this code which when run will produce that 5 row data frame:  `structure(list(speed = c(4, 4, 7, 7, 8), dist = c(2, 10, 4, 22, 
16)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))`  . It does not trim data.

Comment: also note that dput has a file= argument if you want to write it to a file and then paste that into your script.

Comment: My mistake. I like it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, you can paste directly to your R script and use read.table:

```r
data <- read.table( text=
"  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
5     8   16
", header=TRUE )
```

That was copy pasted from an R session where I printed the data.frame from your example.

As for the SQL part, at least the create table definition is fairly easily accessible by borrowing from sqlite:

```r
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "data", data)
cat( DBI::dbReadTable( con, "sqlite_master" )[,"sql"], "\n" )
```

Outputs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `speed` INTEGER,
  `dist` INTEGER
)
```

To dump the data I don't know of any way to get help from the driver, you likely have to manually wrap each row in an insert statement, but sorting out the types is the most laborsome part anyway, and the driver does help with that.

Comment: Thank you. That is ok. I mention SQL part just to show what I want to get. I wanted a tool that creates something that G. Grothendieck mentioned in the comment to my question, though is way produces only 6 rows of data. Your alternative is ok though I hope for something producing the script I showed in my question.

Comment: well dput will create R code to recreate what ever you gave it, and as he points out, it does not trim data. dput code chunks are annoyingly less reader friendly though. I'd use read.table with copy pasted structured data or even data.frame(...) code before dput of anything of some size